# Image in Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to learn basic animation using python,
when i tried to insert an image into the tkinter canvas, no error is visible but neither is the image.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from PIL import *


def initiate():
    canvas1 = Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
    canvas1.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    im = PhotoImage(file='flag.gif', height=100, width=100)
    canvas1.create_polygon(10, 10, 0, 20, 20, 20, fill='white')
    print("hi")
    canvas1.create_image(100, 100, image=im)
    print('bye')
    root.update()


root = Tk()
initiate()
root.mainloop()
```

the polygon is successfully crated but image is not being shown.
pls tell me what i am doing wrong here.
i need image to be in the canvas,not in label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work:

```
from tkinter import *

def initiate():
    canvas1 = Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
    canvas1.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    im = PhotoImage(file='flag.gif', height=100, width=200)
    canvas1.create_polygon(10, 10, 0, 20, 20, 20, fill='white')
    label = Label(image=im)
    label.image = im
    print("hi")
    canvas1.create_image(100, 100, image=im)
    print('bye')
    root.update()

root = Tk()
initiate()
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

See [Why do my Tkinter images not appear?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Why not saving the reference of image to `canvas1.image` instead of a hidden label?